# How can I update the cellls value +1, using panda DataFrames, but only if an if statement is true?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, counting

I have a csv file with multiple headers and numbers inside of them. If the algorithm finds two equal column values within the same row, another DataFrame should update a cell +1 and count the amount of times the algorithm can find such equal cells. How do I do that?

```
import pandas

final_activities = pandas.read_csv("VPN2/VPN2_Final_Activities.csv", delimiter=';', names=['Timerels', 'ActivityClass_Ankle', 'ActivityClass_Hip', 'ActivityClass_Thigh', 'ActivityClass_Wrist', 'ActivityClass_Annotation'], skip_blank_lines=True, skipinitialspace=True, engine='python', header=0)

matricsFile = pandas.read_csv("VPN2/VPN2_Final_Matrics.csv", delimiter=';', names=['lying', 'cycling', 'ascending stairs', 'jogging', 'descending stairs', 'walking', 'standing', 'sitting', 'unknown'], skip_blank_lines=True, skipinitialspace=True, engine='python', header=0)

lying = 1
cycling = 3
ascending_stairs = 4
jogging = 5
descending_stairs = 6
walking = 7
standing = 9
sitting = 11
unknown = 0

i = 0
while i < len(final_activities):
    ankle_activity = final_activities.loc[i]['ActivityClass_Ankle']
    annotation_activity = final_activities.loc[i]['ActivityClass_Annotation']
    
    if(int(annotation_activity) == lying and int(ankle_activity) == lying):
        matricsFile.at[1, 'lying'] += 1
    i += 1
```

Comment: create a boolean mask vector of the if statement, create a vector of the column for all rows updated, update the dataframe with the mask using the new values

Comment: A simplified (reproducible) example with input data and expected result would make the demonstration of a solution much easier.  It is inefficient and (almost) never necessary to loop over DF rows as you are doing.

Comment: I found a solution to my problem:
matricsFile.at[0, 'lying'] = (matricsFile.at[0, 'lying'] + 1)

Comment: If you found a solution, you can post an answer to your own question. This is helpful for people who might have a similar problem in the future.